# boost::shared_ptr seems to disappear when using Linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am using a boost::shared_ptr to point to a plugin class. Plugin is a map <string, shared_ptr>. The first time I find a certain plugin in the map, it works fine. However, any subsequent time I try to find a particular plugin, I get a SIGSEGV error. When stepping through my code, I get to `foundPlugin = a->second->onCommand(command);`and find that a->second is not accessible anymore. This error only happens when I am running in Linux, however. I have no issues while running in Windows. Is there some sort of issue with boost::shared_ptr and linux? I have tried using std::shared_ptr, but I have to use a boost::dll::import function that returns a boost::shared_ptr, and I haven't found an alternative for that yet. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

I load plugins like this:

```
bool PluginManager::loadPlugin(std::string pluginPath, std::string 
                               pluginName, std::string pluginType)
{
    bool couldLoad = false;
    boost::filesystem::path libPath = boost::filesystem::current_path(); 
    boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_api> plugin; 

    std::cout << "Loading the plugin " << pluginName << std::endl;

    if (pluginName == "")
    {
        pluginName = "plugName";
    }

    try
    {
        plugin = boost::dll::import<my_plugin_api>(                    
        libPath / pluginName,                           
        pluginType,                                     
        dll::load_mode::append_decorations              
        );

        Plugin.insert(std::pair<std::string,boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_api>> 
        (pluginName, plugin));
        std::cout << "Loading the plugin " << pluginName << " (SUCCESS)" << 
        std::endl;
        couldLoad = true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return couldLoad;
}
```

After much more testing, I feel like my problems are in the above section of code. the boost::dll::import function acts as if it finds a .so, but does not return anything in the boost::shared_ptr, which in turn causes the second snippet of code to fail. Any ideas of why this boost::dll::import function might be acting weirdly in Linux?

```
bool PluginManager::onCommand(const char* command, const char* pluginName)
{
    bool foundPlugin = false;

    auto a = Plugin.find(pluginName);
    if (a == Plugin.end())
    {
        std::cerr << "plugin " << pluginName << " not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        foundPlugin = a->second->onCommand(command);
    }

    return foundPlugin;
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide a [MRE], otherwise we'd just be guessing :)

Comment: Generally speaking, there are no issues with `boost::shared_ptr` and Linux. The snippet you have provided does not give us enough details to understand what is the bug in your code.

Comment: The issue is that your program has undefined behaviour. It is very difficult to guess where or why, but a common reason for `shared_ptr`s apparently disappearing is handing ownership of an object to more than one "cluster" of sharing owners.

Comment: I'm not sure I can make a minimal reproducible example out of this as it is a very, very large code base and many different components that work together. This snippet was the function where the error was thrown. As I said, somehow, windows handles shared_ptr just fine. It's just Linux where I have issues and I'm not sure what could be different, other than compilers, VS vs GCC 6.4.

Comment: Does your code use multiple threads? Maybe caused by data race.

Comment: No, I'm not using any multi-threading. I have updated my question, as I have done more testing and have, possibly, tracked down the problem. I have edited my question to reflect this.